# Plugin not loaded in CakePHP 3.7.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have create custom plugin with name "Administrator" inside plugin folder. I have also add folder required. I have add following code:

Inside : **plugins/Administrator/config/route.php**

```
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
Router::plugin(
    'Administrator',
       ['path' => '/admin'],
       function ($routes) {
          $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
       }
  );
```

Inside : **src/Application.php**

```
$this->addPlugin('Administrator', ['routes' => true]);
```

Inside : **config/route.php**

```
$routes->scope('/admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->loadPlugin('Administrator');
});
```

Inside browser when I enter http://localhost/c3app/admin/users

It shows error "**Error: AdminController could not be found.** "

I have added code in **composer.json** file

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Administrator" : "./plugins/Administrator/src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Test\\": "tests/",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/",
        "Administrator" : "./plugins/Administrator/src"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins have to be registered in composer.json since CakePHP 3.7.* to ensure autoload.

This error can happen if you create the plugin manually or use `cake bake plugin` and you do **not** override the the `composer.json` (which is default).

If you load the plugin in `App\Application::bootstrap()` via

`$this->addPlugin('Admin', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);`

it triggers a method in `Cake\Http\BaseApplication::makePlugin` which calls the **class_exists()** function. But this only works if the plugin is registered in composer/autoload and the class will be found.

To solves this issue please add the plugin to the `composer.json`file:

`"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Administrator\\": "./plugins/Administrator/src/"
        }
    },`

and refresh the composer autoload files:

`composer dumpautoload`

<s>seems to be a bug in CakePHP 3.7.0. and 3.7.1.</s>

Not a bug, see  CodeWhisperer's comment

Comment: Anyway you have to add the plugin to the composer.json

Comment: have added code in composer file and execute command composer dumpautoload

Comment: It's not a bug. Also in versions below 3.7 you have to refresh the autoload files. Otherwise the new changes will not be added. See the docs [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, files should be named `routes.php` instead of `route.php`.

In `config/routes.php` remove code.
Next, in `plugins/Administrator/config/routes.php` add code below:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->plugin('Administrator', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });
});
```

In `config/bootstrap.php` add code below:

```
Plugin::load('Auth', [
    'autoload' => true,
    'routes' => true,
]);
```

Comment: After adding this its shows error Deprecated (16384): Plugin::load() is deprecated.

Comment: After changing the file name its working but shows Missing Controller  C:\xampp\htdocs\c3app\plugins\Administrator\src\Controller\UsersController.php